# Apache Commons FTPClient, check if remote directory exist and get permissions (linux - unix)

Tags: java, ftp, ftp-client, apache-commons-net

Is it possible with FTPClient (Apache commons-net) to check if a remote directory exists?

I want to do something like this:

```
ftp.isDirectory(String path) //returns true, false
```

And then get permissions (chmod) of directory:

```
ftp.getPermisions(String path) //returns -rwxr-xr-x
```

Answer (score 17):

Try to change the working directory to the directory you need to check:

```
boolean directoryExists = FTPClient.changeWorkingDirectory("path/to/somedir")
```

Comment: This seems to be the only way to really do this, unfortunately.  I think it's just more the limitations of FTP than the client.

Answer (score 7):

What you just Need to check is just `ftpClient.cwd("your Directory Name")`

this will return you integer values

`250` - If File Exists

OR

`550` - If File Doesn't Exist

For Example,

```
if(ftpClient.cwd(uploadDirectoryPath)==550){
     System.out.println("Directory Doesn't Exists");
}else if(ftpClient.cwd(uploadDirectoryPath)==250){
     System.out.println("Directory Exists");
}else{
     System.out.println("Unknown Status");
}
```

Comment: The CWD command means - Change Working Directory btw, so its not really different from boolean directoryExists = FTPClient.changeWorkingDirectory("path/to/somedir")

Comment: Yes, it is same but I gave this example as there is some other status also which we can handle. And we can have more control over our coding that's why.

Comment: If you send CWD, you will lost last working directory. Sometimes it would be the problem when handle multi-thread situation.

Comment: @Aura yes exactly, happened with me I don't  want to change last working directory.

Answer (score 1):

I needed to figure this out too, but after doing a little play, I think I figured it out. I havent gotten to test this yet, but I think it will do the trik

```
FTPFile file[];
file = new FTPFile[ftpClient.listFiles().length];
for (int i = 0; i<file.length; i++) {
if (file[i].getName() == "directory name") {
    if (file[i].isDirectory()) {
    //Do stuff if it is a directory here
         if (file[i].hasPermission(access, permission) {
        //Do whatever you want with permissions - access and permission arguments are int's
                        }
    }
}
}
```

Hope this works/helps. This also seems like a pretty redundant way, so there may be a better way of doing it. Idk, im new to this library and android

Answer (score 0):

If the remote host supports it, the simplest method is [mlistFile()](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPClient.html#mlistFile(java.lang.String)).

```
if (ftpClient.featureValue("MLST") != null) {
    FTPFile file = ftpClient.mlistFile(null);
    boolean b = file.hasPermission(FTPFile.USER_ACCESS, FTPFile.WRITE_PERMISSION);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my take on to find whether given path represents a directory or a file.

```
public static boolean isFtpPathDirectory(String file_path)
{
        try (InputStream inputStream=ftpClient.retrieveFileStream(file_path))
        {
            return inputStream == null;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return false;
        }


}
```